# Using the clock on BASYS 3

Tags: vhdl, clock, vivado

I want to use the clock of the BASYS 3 for my project. When I search for the constraint of the Project I found the following code:

```
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W5 [get_ports clk] 
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports clk] 
create_clock -add -name sys_clk_pin -period 10.00 -waveform {0 5} [get_ports clk]
```

Could someone explain it to me? I know `clk` is the input for the clock but in the last line what should I do? Should I change anything? Also what period 10.00 and `waveform{0 5}` means? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These lines are Xilinx Design Constraints  (XDC), which are a flavor of Synopsys Design Constraints  (SDC).

First you shout distinguish between physical constraints (line 1-2) and timing constraints (line 3). These are required at different steps in the design flow.

```
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W5 [get_ports clk]
```

This lines connect your top-level port `clk` to pin `W5`.

```
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports clk]
```

This line sets the I/O standard needed by timing analysis for the rise and fall times at the pin, resulting in a setup/hold time window

```
create_clock -add -name sys_clk_pin -period 10.00 -waveform {0 5} [get_ports clk]
```

This defines a clock signal of 100 MHz with 50% duty cycle for wire `clk`. If you need to refer to this clock in another statement, you can use the name `sys_clk_pin`.